# Move images into a folder in the public folder in Laravel but fails

Tags: php, laravel, image, upload, storage

I have three folders (userImages, productImages and clientImages) inside the images folder with the public folder in a Laravel(9.5.1) project. I am trying to upload images and move same into the productImages folder but it is not working. However, if I try with the userImages folder, it works and works only with that folder. I would be glad for any assistance from you. Thank you for your assistance in advance.
This is code:

```
if($request->hasFile('product_image')){
    $image          = $request->file('product_image');
    $newImageName   = uniqid().'-'.Str::slug($request->product).'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $location       = public_path('/images/productImages');
    $image->move($location, $newImageName);
}else {
    $newImageName   = 'default_image.png';
}
```

The error message I get from the above line of code is:

> The stream or file "/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pos/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied The exception occurred while attempting to log: The stream or file

Comment: Nothing here appears to be logging? Are you sure this is the code?? Please show the whole error message including filename and line number

Comment: `$newImageName` requires a path as well as a filename

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/filesystem#copying-moving-files

Comment: Thanks RiggsFolly. The error does not show filename and line number apart from the one I indicated in the problem above. The file is moved with no errors when I change the $location = public_path('/images/productImages'); to $location = public_path('/images/userImages');

Answer (score 0):

You need to be specific with the directory you want to allow the permission. Like below for your case.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/pos/public/images/productImages
```

Answer (score -1):

Please make 777 for storage folder permissions. Laravel tries to log the error to the log file. But storage folder permissions don't let it. Then you will see what is wrong with your code in the log file.

```
sudo chmod -R 777 storage
```